# Foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two simple tables `Customers` and `Orders` with relation `oneToMany` from `customer` to `Orders` table.

This is my `Customers.java`

```
@Entity
public class Customers implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cID;
private String name;
private String email;

// getter and setters
}
```

And this is `Orders.java`:

```
@Entity
public class Orders implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int orderID;
private int cId;
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Customers customers;
// getter and setters
}
```

Now, i am going to insert two record in `Orders` table:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Orders orders1 = new Orders();
    Orders orders2 = new Orders();
    Customers customer = new Customers();
    customer.setName("c1");
    customer.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");

    orders1.setDate(new Date());
    orders2.setDate(new Date());

    orders1.setCustomers(customer);
    orders2.setCustomers(customer);

    session.save(orders1);
    session.save(orders2);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

This is the result in console:

```
Hibernate: alter table Orders drop foreign key FK_hmbx2rg9tsgqikb3kodqp90c4
Hibernate: drop table if exists Customers
Hibernate: drop table if exists Orders
Hibernate: create table Customers (cID integer not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (cID))
Hibernate: create table Orders (orderID integer not null auto_increment, cId integer not null, date date not null, customers_cID integer, primary key (orderID))
Hibernate: alter table Orders add constraint FK_hmbx2rg9tsgqikb3kodqp90c4 foreign key (customers_cID) references Customers (cID)
Feb 24, 2015 1:58:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into Customers (email, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Orders (cId, customers_cID, date) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Orders (cId, customers_cID, date) values (?, ?, ?)
```

And this is the result tables:

[image]

Why the `cID` in `Orders` table (which is a foreign key references to `customers`) is `0`?

It should be `1`.

Comment: What is the difference between `cId` and `customers_cId` in table `Orders`. Are you referencing the right key?

Comment: @Nfear There is no difference between them. Why i have two foreign key?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think in your `orders` table `customers_cId` is the actual foreign key reference column to the `customers` table. As you haven't gave any column name explicitly, it internally took column name as `customers_cId` by joining the variables from both the entities. `customers` from the `orders` and `cId` from the `customers` entity.

Just to verify you can try giving some other name using `@JoinColumn` annotation.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="order_cId") 
private Customers customers;
```

And `cId` in `orders` table is just one more independent column, as you have not set any value to it, its taking the default value as `0`. Try setting some random value to it.